# fetch rows when u dont know in which column value is present(On basis of sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select only those columns where a particular value is present so i can a get a row as a result set but the problem is i dont know in which column the value is present for maintaining the dynamic nature.

As i am making a timetable software so i want to get faculty timetable from the tables of various semesters of different branches , so i am not able to obtain a logic as how to fetch rows on basis of value when u dont know in which column the value(faculty) is present(On basis of sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you will need to pivot data first to get new structure:

If you had columns: ID - COLUMN1 - COLUMN2 - COLUMN2 - ... - COLUMN(n)

after pivoting you will get:

ID - COLUMNS - VALUES

It will be easy to query this table and find out which column has value